# Table view cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use TableView with selected button, I have a problem with my code because when the button is selected, I don't know what is the IndexPath of my cell.

I use a file TableView cell with table view cell.xib

```
@IBOutlet weak var lbTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbDetail: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnCheckMark: UIButton!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

In my View controller I have this :

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.topBar.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Apply", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.apply))
    self.topBar.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backButton"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(backHome))
    listeView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CheckList")
    listeView.dataSource = self
    listeView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return deviceData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let rowpath = indexPath.row
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckList") as! TableViewCell
    cell.lbTitle.text = "\(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].brandName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].modelName)"
    cell.lbDetail.text = "\(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].operatorName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].version), \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].browserName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].version)"
    //cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.btnCheckMark.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkMarkButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    let test = TableViewCell()
    test.lbTitle.text = "11"

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 71.0
}
@objc func checkMarkButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        nb -= 1
        //rint(paramaters)
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
        paramaters["devicesList[\(nb)][deviceId]"] = id
        nb += 1
    }
    print(paramaters)
}
```

In my function checkMarkButton, I want to know the indexPath.row

Comment: You can add this logic for the button action inside the custom cell subclass you added. Also if you add a property to that cell `indexPath` and set it from the controller every time you use the cell you will have a correct reference to the current index path for your button.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift the most efficient way is a **callback closure**.

It's pretty easy: No protocols, no target/action, no delegate, no tags, no index paths, no view math, no `@objc` attribute.

- In the **model** representing `deviceData` add a property `isSelected`

  ```
  var isSelected = false
  ```
- In the **cell** add a property `callback` and an `IBAction`. Connect the button to the `IBAction`. In the `IBAction` the selection state is toggled and the callback is called

  ```
  var callback : ((UIButton) -> Void))?

  @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
     sender.isSelected.toggle()
     callback?(sender)
  }
  ```
- In the **view controller** set and handle the callback in `cellForRow`

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      //let rowpath = indexPath.row
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckList") as! TableViewCell
      let data = self.deviceData[indexPath.row]
      cell.lbTitle.text = "\(data.brandName) \(data.modelName)"
      cell.lbDetail.text = "\(data.operatorName) \(data.version), \(data.browserName) \(data.version)"
      cell.btnCheckMark.isSelected = data.isSelected
      cell.callback { button in 
           self.deviceData[indexPath.row].isSelected = button.isSelected
           // or if deviceData is a class with reference semantics
           // data.isSelected = button.isSelected
      }
      return cell
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass button with the property of Indexpath and use that button instead.

So:

```
class ButtonWithIndexPath : UIButton {
    var indexPath:IndexPath?
}
```

Then assign the property to your new button in the cellforRowAt method in your table when you assign all the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tableView.indexPath(for: UITableViewCell)` to get the whole IndexPath for your cell.

Example use:

```
@objc func checkMarkButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // do something else

    guard let cell = sender.superview as? UITableViewCell, let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        return
    }

    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Use `if let` instead of `guard let`, if you do not want to terminate execution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right way to do that, Instead try to use the didSelectRowAt delegate function and update the data, like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        data[indexPath.row].selected = !data[indexPath.row].selected
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }

    //then on the cellForRowAt:
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CheckList") as! TableViewCell
     cell.lbTitle.text = "\(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].brandName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].modelName)"
     cell.lbDetail.text = "\(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].operatorName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].version), \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].browserName) \(self.deviceData[indexPath.row].version)"
    //cell.selectionStyle = .none
     cell.setSelected(data[indexPath.row].selected, animated: true)
     return cell
    }
```

that way the tableView and your data are synchronized.