# Why is that? Button toggles the state on a custom cell whose background image is reused by other cells

Tags: ios, swift

Button on a custom cell to toggle the background image state, which is reused by other cells, should be reuse problem, but do not know how to solve? Can you give me some advice?

```
    @objc func LickCheck(_ sender:UIButton){
        //Toggle button background image
        if !sender.isSelected {
          //code
        }else{
         //code
        }
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : FoneCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Focid", for: indexPath) as! FoneCell;

        cell.xxBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

        cell.xxBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LickCheck), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside);

        return cell;
        }
```

FoneCell.swift：

```
lazy var xxxBtn : UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton();
        btn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "love_18x18_"), for: UIControl.State.normal);
        btn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "love_on_20x20_"), for: UIControl.State.selected)


        return btn;
    }();
```

Comment: You need to store `loveBtn` `isSelected` state for future reusable cells.

Comment: What `addDate` and `deleteDate` does?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613618/table-view-cell-selected/53614485#53614485

Comment: addDate is Store the data

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem,
First, define an array of global records that clicked over the button

```
    lazy var numbercells:[Int] = []
```

Secondly, in the

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : FoneCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Focid", for: indexPath) as! FoneCell;

        if self.numbercells.contains(indexPath.row){
            cell.loveBtn.isSelected = true;
        }else{
            cell.loveBtn.isSelected = false;

        }
        cell.loveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LickCheck), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside);
        cell.loveBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

        return cell;

    }
```

The last

```
    @objc func LickCheck(_ sender:UIButton){

        if !sender.isSelected {
            self.numbercells.append(sender.tag);
            addDate(sender.tag)
        }else{
            self.numbercells = self.numbercells.filter(){$0 != sender.tag}
            deleteDate(sender.tag)
        }
        let posinton = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0);
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [posinton], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.none)

    }
```

This solves the button select state reuse problem on the cell

Answer (score 0):

This should be something like,

**FoneCell.swift**:

```
protocol FoneCellDelegate: class {
   func didSelectButton(atIndex: Int)
}

@IBOutlet var loveBtn: UIButton!

public weak var delegate: FoneCellDelegate?

func awakeFromNib() {
   super.awakeFromNib()
   loveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LickCheck), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside);
}

 @objc func LickCheck(_ sender:UIButton){
        //Toggle button background image
        if !sender.isSelected {
            addDate(sender.tag)
        }else{
            deleteDate(sender.tag)
        }
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
        delegate?.didSelectButton(atIndex: sender.tag)
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var buttonStates =  Array(repeating: false, count: 10)//if you need 10 rows

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return buttonStates.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : FoneCell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Focid", for: indexPath) as! FoneCell;

    cell.loveBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.loveBtn.isSelected = buttonStates[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self // Implement protocol on cell's class. And update the value in buttonStates when state toggled
    return cell
}

func didSelectButton(atIndex: Int) {
      buttonStates[atIndex] = !buttonStates[atIndex]
      tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the problem is that the select state of the button on the cell will be reused by other cells

Comment: cell.loveBtn.isSelected = buttonStates[indexPath.row]
 Thanks for the comment, but there is something wrong with this code

Comment: i didnt use mac now. So I can't write this code in xcode. please take the idea. and write as your own. I dont think there is a syntax error in this code.

Comment: initially all your buttons are in unselected state, so i just created an array with 10 elements which having false value

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have solved the problem

Comment: I want to know, how about you `    cell.delegate = self // Implement protocol on cell's class. And update the value in buttonStates when state toggled
`

Comment: how you store the state change into `buttonStates` array?

Comment: Yes, I don't quite understand what you're thinking. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: How you achieve that?

Comment: No, no, I was wondering how you store the state change into buttonStates array?Can you update your code

Comment: using delegates. Please find tutorial for delegation using protocols. I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in override method of UITableViewCell

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
          super.prepareForReuse()
      //set default state here 
     self.imageView.image = nil
     self.toggleButton.isOn = false 
//.....
    }
```

or you can do the same in tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    //Set default behaviour here
    cell.imageView.image = nil 
    cell.toggleButton.isOn = false 
  ....
return cell
```

P.S you can make array in viewController for save the state of button selected.
e.g

```
let isSelectedArray = Array(repeating: false, count: 100)
@objc func LickCheck(_ sender:UIButton){
        //Toggle button background image
        let tag = sender.tag
        if !isSelectedArray[tag]{

          //code
        }else{
         //code
        }
        isSelectedArray[tag] = !isSelectedArray[tag]
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, now the problem is that the select state of the button on the cell will be reused by other cells

Comment: in prepareForUse or before returning the cell you can set it to default state
cell.button.selectionState = .normal

Comment: I'm really sorry that I didn't make it clear. I just want to switch the button selection state, but I want to switch a certain cell, and some other cells switch together

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao please check updated answer you have to track selection as i had written sample code above

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have adopted other methods to solve the problem. I don't quite understand the code you just updated before, so I can't get your idea