# every time a cell with an enabled button disappears a new cell inserts with an already activated button

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

[image: first cell with manually activated button]

[image: i have added a few new cells]

[image: the first cell with the enabled button disapears and the new added cell has automatically an enabled button]

I have created a cell in a xib file with an `UIButton`. The button is an `checkmarkbutton` so when i click it it shows a checkmark. When i enable a button in a cell and i add a few new cells and the cell with the enabled checkmarkbutton disapears from the view of the tableview there comes automatically a new cell with a button that is already enabled. How can i stop that ?

```
var sliderValues = [String]()

    @IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
        sliderValues.insert("\(Int(waterAmountSlider.value)) L", at: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 65.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sliderValues.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xibcell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


        cell.cellWaterAmountLabel.text = sliderValues[indexPath.row]
//      cell.cellLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
```

***xib cell code***

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var cellWaterAmountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func cellButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "enabledCheckbox"), for: UIControl.State.normal)    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common issue with UITableViewCells. You need to add some code in your `cellForRowAt` method to manage the appearance of the button. Basically, the `UITableView` stores copies of the cells you have used, and reuses them instead of making new ones.

Comment: okay what kind of code do you mean

Comment: `cell.button.isEnabled = false`

Comment: now i cant enable the button at all

Comment: Oh right, do the one that affects the UI you are working with. `isEnabled` is disabling the button. Looks like that is `cellButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "disabledCheckbox"), for: UIControl.State.normal)`

Comment: As I said in your previous question you need a model (a custom struct) which contains a String (one of the items in `sliderValues`) and a Bool for the `isSelected` state. Update both values in `cellForRow` and add a callback to get notified when the button is pressed to update `isSelected` in the model. And please don't make worse my suggested code. **Don't** call `reloadData()`right after `insertRows`. Never do that.

Comment: okay but now the other cells with an enabled button are reset to the disabledCheckbox

Comment: okay but i dont understand how i build this struct. how do i write this code

Comment: This is very basic stuff. Please read [Swift Language Guide: Structures and Classes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613618/table-view-cell-selected/53614485#53614485) is an example how to implement the callback

Answer (score 0):

It is reusing the cells you have already created. To avoid this behavior you have to catch and update the state when the button's cell is updated.

This can be a possible solution:

```
var sliderValues = [(String, Bool)]()

@IBAction func addNewCell(_ sender: Any) {
    sliderValues.insert(("\(Int(waterAmountSlider.value)) L", false), at: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 65.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sliderValues.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "xibcell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.cellWaterAmountLabel.text = sliderValues[indexPath.row].0
    cell.isButtonSelected = sliderValues[indexPath.row].1
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    cell.changeHandler = { text, isOn in
        sliderValues[indexPath.row] = (text, isOn)
    }

    return cell
}
```

And this would be the Table View Cell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var isButtonSelected: Bool = false
    var changeHandler: ((String, Bool) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var cellButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var cellWaterAmountLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func cellButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        isButtonSelected.toggle()
        let image = isButtonSelected ? UIImage(named: "enabledCheckbox") : UIImage(named: "disabledCheckbox")
        cellButton.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        changeHandler?(cellButton.titleLabel?.text ?? "", isButtonSelected)
    }
}
```

Comment: the xib file code says "class TableViewCell has no initializers"

Comment: i have copied the code but i still have the same problem

Comment: the tableview is still copying the cells when they disappear from the view of the the tableview

Comment: Copy only the Table View Cell logic. It already has the params initialized.

Comment: now the wateramountlabel.value also disappaers when i disable the button and add a new cell afterwards

Comment: okay no it is working good but theres still the problem with the copied cells