# tableviewcell changing the images while scrolling

Tags: swift, image, button, scroll, tableview

I have four button inside a tableview cell and each of the button has a unique as 0,1,2 and 3 respectively.
These four buttons and linked to a single button action method.
The code inside tableviewcell is as follows:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var questionLbl: UILabel!
  
     @IBOutlet weak var q1: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var q2: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var q3: UIButton!
     @IBOutlet weak var q4: UIButton!
    typealias emptyButtonClosure = (String,Int) -> ()
    var buttonTapped:emptyButtonClosure?
 @IBAction func btnClicked(sender:UIButton){

        let buttonArray = [q1,q2,q3,q4]
 
        for button in buttonArray {
           
            if sender.tag == button!.tag{
                
                button!.isSelected = true;
                if let buttonTapped = buttonTapped{
                    buttonTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text!,sender.tag)
                }
              
                if let image = UIImage(named: "checked-radio") {
                     button!.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                }
                else
                {
                    let image1 = UIImage(named: "unchecked-radio")
                    button!.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                }
               
            }else{
               
                button!.isSelected = false;
               if let image = UIImage(named: "unchecked-radio") {
                     button!.setImage(image, for: .normal)
                }
               else
               {
                   let image1 = UIImage(named: "checked-radio")
                   button!.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

These buttons are grouped into single array called as buttonarray because these buttons are radio buttons and only single selection is allowed.
Now the issue is,the value is fetched correctly for each cell in the tableview.But when the tableview is scrolled,the image position keeps changing.The code inside tableview is as follows:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        

        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "questioncell", for: indexPath) as! ChildQuestionCell
        

        cell.questionLbl.text = self.listData?.nanniBookingDetails.questionsData[indexPath.row].question

     cell.q1.setTitle(self.listData?.nanniBookingDetails.questionsData[indexPath.row].option1, for: .normal)
        cell.q2.setTitle(self.listData?.nanniBookingDetails.questionsData[indexPath.row].option2, for: .normal)
        cell.q3.setTitle(self.listData?.nanniBookingDetails.questionsData[indexPath.row].option3, for: .normal)
        cell.q4.setTitle(self.listData?.nanniBookingDetails.questionsData[indexPath.row].option4, for: .normal)
        
        cell.buttonTapped = { value,index in
            print("button selected is",value,index)
            self.answers.append(value)
        }

return cell
}
```

How to retain the image position even when it is scrolled.Like the image selected for 1st row should not be shown in 3rd or 4th row.It should remain only in 1st row.
Please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: Cells are reused. You have to maintain the state of the radio button somewhere preferably in the data model.

Comment: Data mode of which one?

Comment: In `questionsData`

Comment: thats the data from the API

Comment: Yes, but this is the best place to keep all data related to the UI.

Comment: its a get method,so i can only get the data from the API.how can i maintain the state of the button inside this API? or can u suggest me any third party library to use radio button inside tableview?

Comment: Actually you need only to keep the tag of the selected button. It’s a simple logic, an extra library is not necessary. In the callback closure update the model

Comment: Could you please tell m how to do it?i have tried many ways but in vain.right now each button has the unique tag from 0,1,2 and 3.These buttons are inside tableview cell.

Comment: Basically it's the same pattern as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53613618/table-view-cell-selected/53614485#53614485). But instead of a `Bool` use an `Int` (or even an enum) and select the proper button in `cellForRow`

Comment: let me check that and get back to you

Comment: i checked that answer,but the thing is i have 4 buttons unlike in that case,where it is single button.

Comment: You have 4 buttons but one callback. As you are passing the tag of the button you can save it easily.

Comment: yeah tag is button is different,how can i write a callback for a single button only?

Comment: Why? You are dealing with radio buttons. Once again, you need to keep the tag of the currently selected button. Select the  corresponding button in `cellForRow` (and deselect the others) and in the callback update the model. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: button in form of radio button is what im using.

Comment: i tried to replicate the same as your solution given in another question.But not able to get the logic for 4 buttons.Could you please show a sample code with my scenario.